# Why does Spring Boot generates a jar?

Tags: spring, tomcat, jar, spring-boot, war

Why does Spring Boot generates a `jar` file output, since a `jar` could not be deployed to a container or an application server?

It's nice to get it quickly set up (with an embedded container), but eventually you will have to build a `war` file in order to deploy the application properly.

Furthermore, it is a good choice to stick with spring boot also when the project is in production? From my point of view spring boot is just as a quick way to get started, but I'm not sure about it's reliability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring boot creates the jar/war based of the build tool packaging configuration. If you mention the packaging type as war then spring boot will create `.war` file.

Use the following configurations then you will get `.war`.

**Maven**

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

**Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'war'
```

Comment: Thank you for your good and quick answer. But a `.war` also needs a web descriptor (i.e. `web.xml`). Am I right? And furthermore, it is a good choice to stick with spring boot also when the project is in production? For now I see spring boot just as a quick way to get started, but I'm not sure about it's reliability.

Comment: Not excatly if you are using Servlet 3.0+ you dont need an web.xml Check http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-traditional-deployment

Comment: Awesome! I did not come across with this information. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind the jar is that you can run your app standalone without any container (see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-first-application-executable-jar).